# How can I use bindkey to run a script in ZSH?

Tags: zsh

In ZSH, how can I use `bindkey` to bind a key sequence to a script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a widget that calls your script:

```
my-script_widget() my-script its args
zle -N my-script_widget
bindkey '\ej' my-script_widget
```

But why would you want to call your script directly from the zle?

If it displays anything, it will mess up the display. If you want its output displayed as other widget messages, you can do:

```
my-script_widget() zle -M "$(my-script its args)"
```

Or if you want the output inserted at the cursor:

```
my-script_widget() LBUFFER+=$(my-script its args)
```

Comment: Do you place this code in `~/.zshrc` - or another location?

Answer (score 12):

I think you do not need widget for that:

```
bindkey -s '\eb' '/path/to/script.sh\n'
```

From [zsh docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html):

> As well as ZLE commands, key sequences can be bound to other strings, by using ‘bindkey -s’.

Comment: That doesn't bind `Alt-B` to the script, that causes `/path/to/script.sh\n` to be inserted as if typed. For instance if you type `Alt-B` after having entered `echo `, that will just run the `echo /path/to/script.sh` command and get you back to an empty prompt (with the `echo ` you had entered earlier gone).

Comment: Yes, you are right. But still _inserted as if typed_ is enough in some use cases.

Comment: Add an enter at the end of the string and the script will get executed after being inserted, `bindkey -s '\eb' '/path/to/script.sh^M'`

Comment: @mihai Thanks for your comment.  It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on [@suside](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117885/suside)'s answer:

Since `bindkey -s` just sends key sequences, if theres already something on your prompt and you try and use the binding, it just types it in after whats already at the prompt. This can be fixed by sending `kill-whole-line` to clear the prompt before typing your command/script in.

`kill-whole-line` is typically bound to `^u` (`Ctrl+U`), see [docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html). If its not, you can bind it with:

`bindkey '^u' kill-whole-line`

Then, you can do:

```
bindkey -s '\eb' '^u/path/to/script.sh^M'
```

which binds `Alt+b` to kill the current line before typing your characters, then sending `^M` (newline).